# Protected связь через Parent

Tags: php, ооп

```
abstract class Component {
    protected $x = 123;
}

class A extends Component {
    private $b;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B();
        //$this->b->x = 234;
    }

    public function getBX() {
        return $this->b->x;
    }
}

class B extends Component {
    //protected $x = 777;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->x = 567;
    }
}

echo (new A())->getBX();

try{
    (new B())->x = null;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Как и ожидалось';
}
```

Я что-то в этой жизни пропустил. Почему property **x** доступна как **public**? PHP работает с **protected** не только с дочерними элементами, но и связывает их через **parent**?

Comment: Что Вас смущает? Всё верно.

Comment: Ну то что доступ к **protected** можно получить в двух случаях. Либо из самого класса, либо из дочернего класса. Тоесть в случае с **x**, либо внутри **Component** либо внутри дочерних классов **A** и **B**. Но почему в классе **A** я могу получить к  доступ к **protected** свойству класса **B**, он ведь не дочерний от **A**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом это [документированное](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php) поведение:

> **Видимость из других объектов**
>
> Объекты, которые имеют общий тип (**наследуются от одного класса**), имеют
>   доступ к элементам с модификаторами `private` и `protected` друг друга,
>   даже если не являются одним и тем же экземпляром. Это объясняется тем,
>   что реализация видимости элементов известна внутри этих объектов

Хотя если прочитать оригинал документации, то данный абзац там выглядит иначе:

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others `private` and `protected` members even though they are not the same instances. This is because the implementation specific details are already known when inside those objects.

Как видно здесь нет никаких *"наследуются от одного класса"*. А просто речь идет, когда два экземпляра объекта одного и того же класса, имеют доступ к `private` полям друг друга. Это в принципе нормально, и имеет место быть в любых других языках.

Поэтому интересно бы узнать, откуда появилась эта приписка в рускоязычной документации, т.к. именно она отражает ситуацию, описанную в данном вопросе.

Тем не менее, по определению

> Модификатор `protected` (защищенный) разрешает доступ самому классу, наследующим его классам и **родительским классам**.

общий родительский класс играет свою роль, и если вы перенесете `$x` в класс `B`, то доступа уже не получите.

Comment: Разрыв шаблона, в кое то веки в русской документации больше инфы чем в оригинале)